# PHP Session Logic and a small coding issue

Tags: php, session

I am working on PHP login/registration system (part of a big project) and I need to log each visitor request. I am working with session and cookies for the first time so I'm not pretty sure about my logic. First of all, checkout my logic...

**Logic:**

```
public function is_valid_session(){
    if(session_and_cookie_is_empty){
        //first time visitor
        start_new_session();
    } elseif(empty_session_but_not_empty_cookie){
        status = get_session_data_from_db(session_token_from_cookie);
        if(status_is_true){
            if(COOKIE_TOKEN == DATABASE_STORED_TOKEN && CURRENT_IP == DATABASE_STORED_IP && CURRENT_TIME() < DATABASE_STORED_TIME){
                //valid session
            }
        } else{
            //not first visit but IP changed OR session expired
            start_new_session();
        }
    } else{
        if(COOKIE_TOKEN == SESSION_TOKEN && CURRENT_IP == SESSION_IP && CURRENT_TIME() < SESSION_TIME){
                //valid session
        }
    }
}

public function start_new_session(){
    //set IP, USER_EMAIL, TOKEN and START time
}
```

On page visit, I set the `USER_EMAIL` session variable to `0` and it is set to the correct email when the user is logged in successfully. Now I have this code on each member page:

```
if(!empty(SESSION)){
    if(SESSION['USER_EMAIL'] == 0){
        //redirect to login page
    }
}
```

**Questions:**

1. Am I doing in correct way and can it be improved?
2. When the user is logged in, it still shows error: **user is not logged in**. Why is that?

**Screenshot 1** (Output in Browser)
[image]

**Screenshot 2** (Code)
[image]

**PS:** Maybe this is not a good question but believe me, I am struggling from last couple of days and I have no help other than this **community**! And I did not paste actual code because it's very lengthy so it will take more time in reading and understanding so I wrote in simple readable format.

Comment: So in `$_SESSION['USER_EMAIL'] == 0` comparison you're comparing a string with a number `0`. What is it intended to do? Generally, comparing values of different types should be avoided, and in this particular case it is the root of your confusion.

Comment: You use `$_SESSION`, but are you calling the built-in `session_start()` function?

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto they totally do - check their question once again.

Comment: Also the textual code uses `$SESSION` while the picture shows `$_SESSION`....

Comment: @zerkms No mention of `session_start()` in the post...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto in their code they output `$_SESSION['USER_EMAIL']`, which totally has a value. Their problem is in the `== 0` comparison, please do not make them even more confused.

Comment: @zerkms Comparing String with number is really not a bad idea, but should use `===` instead for additional type checking.

Comment: @zerkms What is the better way to resolve it? Should I convert string to int using `intval()` OR ?

Comment: @Alena express with words what you want to do in that very comparison

Comment: @zerkms `$_SESSION` is part of PHP's session modul, that is initialized with the `session_start()` function. Unless it is called, the contents of `$_SESSION` is undetermined, empty at best...

Comment: @zerkms First, I want to set a dummy value in session for Visitors, It can be anything. Second, I want to check if the user value is dummy then redirect to login page(for member pages).

Comment: Yes, but what do you want to express in that `if` statement?

Comment: @zerkms I will call `header()` function in `if` statement (redirecting to login)

Comment: @Alena Just use `===` operator instead of `==`, this should do it...

Comment: @Alena `if(SESSION['USER_EMAIL'] == 0){` --- what is your intention here. Please explain what you wanted to express with this code.

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto you're not helping. `=== 0` totally makes no sense there.

Comment: @zerkms Why does it not make sense?

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto why does it make any sense? You're suggesting to compare a string with a number? How email is comparable with a number `0`?

Comment: Many PHP built-in function return so called `mixed` type values, that is (usually´an object, when the function is successfull, and `FALSE` if an error happened. Those are checked by `if(resutl === FALSE)`....

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto good. How is it relevant to your suggestion of comparing a string with a number `0`? (which, as I mentioned before, is a total nonsense)

Comment: @zerkms If user is not logged in then session variable `$_SESSION['USER_EMAIL']` will have `0` in it because it is stored while starting visitor session. And if it have `0` then the user is not logged in so I can redirect to login page. Hopefully it make sense now.

Comment: @Alena why would it have `0` there? Who puts it there? Why do you put it there at all?

Comment: @zerkms **1. why would it have `0`** Because `0` is set for all visitors. **2. Who puts it there?** Myself, set it as default value **3. Why do you put it there at all?**  Because I need a way to recognize that the user is not logged in and it can be any value other than registered users email. BTW, all the detail was already in question and also mentioned in comments.

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto your trick works, Bundle of thanks! 1. Is it valid way to handle this? 2. Am I handling session and cookie in correct way?

Comment: @Alena you don't need to set it to `0`. For non-authenticated users just don't set anything anywhere. Then check with `isset($_SESSION['USER_EMAIL'])`

Comment: "1. Is it valid way to handle this?" --- it totally is not. Do not mix values of different types in the same variable.

Comment: To both of your questions: If it works, it is fine....

Comment: @zerkms thanks I will keep it empty for visitors. What's your opinion about session logic?

Comment: `is_valid_session` function is a bit (or a lot) strange, and lacks details on where the constants (??) it uses come from and what they carry.

Comment: `is_valid_session` don't accepts any parameter. And it takes value from `$_SESSION`, `$_COOKIE` and from database as well (according to needs). It may helps you, If you re-check the logic.

Comment: It does not help at all: `COOKIE_TOKEN == DATABASE_STORED_TOKEN` here are 2 constants, and not even a single trace on where and how they are declared.

Comment: These are just regular variables like `$_COOKIE['token'] == $data_array['token']` and same for other variables.

Comment: `COOKIE_TOKEN` is not a variable, it's a constant. Variable identifiers start with `$`

Comment: As I mentioned in question, this is not the exact code and gave meaningful name to all variables which tells, 1. What this variable carry? 2. Where does the value came from? **Example:** `COOKIE_TOKEN` means it fetches token from cookie. `DATABASE_STORED_TOKEN` means it gets token from database.